# How to handle kafka consumer failure | Soft commit machanism

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have multiple consumers reading(in fixed batch sizes) from 1 topic with multiple partitions.

Each consumer starts reading at the start of an hour, keeps aggregating(count, sum) in-memory and at the end of the hour it saves the aggregations in SQL.
Each consumer has to  commit(Manual/Auto) the read offsets as soon as possible, so that other consumer don't read the already read offsets. Else, the final aggregations will be incorrect.

The issue is if any consumer fails before saving aggregations in SQL, the offsets already committed by the failed consumer, will be missed by other consumers.
Hence there will be data loss.

Is there any work around to tackle this kind of scenario? I researched for something like soft commit but I think there is nothing of that sort in Kafka.

Comment: Are you using Kafka Streams for the aggregation or are you using the Kafka consumer API directly?

Comment: Using Kafka consumer API. But I think same problem will be there for Kafka Streams as well.