# Storing hourly data in Kafka | Issue with designing consumer for an existing system

Tags: java, apache-kafka, couchbase, kafka-consumer-api

I have to replace Couchbase with Kafka in an existing system. In existing system, docs are being written to Couchbase and a java program reads from it, aggregates data in-memory and stores the data in SQL at the end of an hour.
More details in [this article](https://medium.com/@udit.jindal/frugal-approach-to-scaling-c4d3b100a608).

Now the producer will write to Kafka and that seems straight forward to do. Issue is with the consumer side.

I want each consumer to keep reading from kafka, keep aggregating(count, sum) data in-memory and at the end of the hour save the aggregations in SQL.
I am facing following challenges in this.

- How can I coordinate between multiple consumers? Like if a consumer fails before saving to SQL, then the complete process of that hour data should re-start. [More details in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320234/how-to-handle-kafka-consumer-failure-soft-commit-machanism).
- Should I create a single topic or hourly topic? Hourly topic approach seems good but I want to understand if that's a right approach or not.

Comment: I suggest you use KsqlDB for this with hourly windows. Then query that table, not any external database... That being said, Kafka is not a replacement for Couchbase

Comment: Understood. Will check more about the KsqlDB. 
But how to handle the first question of coordinating between multiple consumers so that all the consumers restart if any of them fails?

Comment: With KSQL specifically? That is handled behind the scenes; Kafka Streams will restart failed tasks but I don't think you want to restart "all" of them

Comment: RE: "I have to replace Couchbase with Kafka" you have a working system in the referenced article you "stated [Couchbase] seemed to be the most suitable option" why do you need to replace Couchbase (cost, it is now unsuitable, etc. ?).  Depending on your reason(s) I might advise different paths to explore.

Comment: @JonStrabala Thank you for going through the details. The reasons for ditching couchbase are 
- It feels CB is not a fit for this kind of usecase.
- Scaling up and down is not easy. Everytime we need to rebalance the cluster. Kafka also has this challenge but there are managed Kafka service that can help us.
- Better community support for Kafka.
- Kafka is a popular choice.
- Since kafka is designed for these usecases only, we might get better throughput and thus be able to reduce cost.

These are the main reasons, please do suggest.

Comment: @UditJindal thanks for the candid feedback, I would recommend WRT hands off scaling up and down that you try out 1) our autonomous operator or our hosted cloud offering 2) Capella.